# What is name of the bottom bar as shown in the image?

Tags: android, view, android-navigation-bar

Please image is given in the following link. What is the term or official term of this bar with the icons together? [image]

Answer (score 6):

It is the Android **Navigation Bar**.

You can find more info in the Material [documentation](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html).

> **Android navigation bar**
>
> The Android navigation bar in Android houses the device navigation controls: Back, Home, and Overview. It also displays a menu for apps written for Android 2.3 or earlier.

[image]

Just a final note.
Android 10 introduced a new immersive look which involves also the look, dimension and the behaviour of Navigation Bar.

[image]